# PythonAnywhere - Difficulty Setting up Selenium with PhantomJS/Chromedriver

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver, pythonanywhere

So I've been stuck on this problem for about a week. Accidentally deleted a virtualenv that I needed and set up a new one and I also went through a small refactoring in my code.

We've been using Selenium to do some webscraping, and everything's been working fine in our dev environment. Here's the code we've been using for Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS("selenium/phantomjs.exe")
browsers[url] = browser
browser.get(url)
```

The main error I've been getting is this:

```
2017-01-20 16:32:35,910 :[2017-01-20 16:32:35,908] ERROR in app: Exception on /processCart [GET]
2017-01-20 16:32:35,910 :Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-01-20 16:32:35,910 :  File "/home/murtazabambot/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
2017-01-20 16:32:35,910 :    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
2017-01-20 16:32:35,910 :  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
2017-01-20 16:32:35,910 :    restore_signals, start_new_session)
2017-01-20 16:32:35,910 :  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1457, in _execute_child
2017-01-20 16:32:35,910 :    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
2017-01-20 16:32:35,911 :PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
2017-01-20 16:32:35,911 :
2017-01-20 16:32:35,911 :During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2017-01-20 16:32:35,911 :
2017-01-20 16:32:35,911 :Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-01-20 16:32:35,911 :  File "/home/murtazabambot/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
2017-01-20 16:32:35,911 :    rv = self.dispatch_request()
2017-01-20 16:32:35,911 :  File "/home/murtazabambot/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
2017-01-20 16:32:35,911 :    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2017-01-20 16:32:35,911 :  File "/home/murtazabambot/InternBlitz/routes/cart.py", line 60, in processCart
2017-01-20 16:32:35,911 :    return findMissingInfo(session['cart'])
2017-01-20 16:32:35,911 :  File "/home/murtazabambot/InternBlitz/routes/cart.py", line 162, in findMissingInfo
2017-01-20 16:32:35,911 :    missingInfo, closed = applicationHandler.findAllMissingInfo(urls, ids, platforms, session)
2017-01-20 16:32:35,911 :  File "/home/murtazabambot/InternBlitz/applicationHandler.py", line 17, in findAllMissingInfo
2017-01-20 16:32:35,912 :    missingInfo.append(greenhouseScripts.findMissingInfo(url))
2017-01-20 16:32:35,912 :  File "/home/murtazabambot/InternBlitz/greenhouseScripts.py", line 57, in findMissingInfo
2017-01-20 16:32:35,912 :    allInfo = findAllInfo(url)
2017-01-20 16:32:35,912 :  File "/home/murtazabambot/InternBlitz/greenhouseScripts.py", line 72, in findAllInfo
2017-01-20 16:32:35,912 :    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS("selenium/phantomjs.exe")
2017-01-20 16:32:35,912 :  File "/home/murtazabambot/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 52, in __init__
2017-01-20 16:32:35,912 :    self.service.start()
2017-01-20 16:32:35,912 :  File "/home/murtazabambot/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 86, in start
2017-01-20 16:32:35,912 :    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
2017-01-20 16:32:35,912 :selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs.exe' executable may have wrong permissions.
```

I've already tried using the "chmod -R 777 chromedriver" fix to get get it working, but then I just get the following error:

```
[Errno 8] Exec format error
```

**The most annoying part about all this is that it was completely working a week ago, but now everything seems to have broken.** So I know it definitely works on PythonAnywhere, I just don't know where the error is stemming from.

Comment: what is `browsers` and `url` in `browsers[url] = browser `? be sure about this line.

Comment: @gunesmes browsers is a dictionary of selenium browsers that i'm storing later use. url is the url that is passed into the method. both of those work fine. i copy pasted the code block from a larger method and forgot to take that line out.

Comment: "Exec format error"? Are you trying to run a windows executable on the PythonAnywhere linux machines?